# Acces-Control-Allow-Origin works with Web.config (IIS7) but not with (WebApiConfig.cs) ASP.NET Cross Origin support

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, cors

For a project i want to load and view a pdf file with angular-pdfjs. The team uses ASP.net Cross Origin, to Allow-Acces-Control, Headers, Credentials etc.

```
    public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Replace the default implementation of the ITraceWriter with our custom logger.
        config.Services.Replace(typeof (ITraceWriter), new GlobalTraceLogger());

        // Replace the default exception logger to be able to log exceptions with NLog
        config.Services.Replace(typeof (IExceptionLogger), new GlobalExceptionLogger());

        // Replace the default exceptionhandler to be able to handle exceptions globally
        config.Services.Replace(typeof (IExceptionHandler), new GlobalExceptionHandler());

        // We must enable cors, because otherwise we are not able to commuincate with a java script client
        // TODO: We need to restirct the requested resource. Do not allow every origin!
        //       Do not run this in prodocutive environment

        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*", "*");
        cors.SupportsCredentials = true;
        config.EnableCors(cors);
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Make the default return type JSON
        var appXmlType =
            config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
```

This works good so far, but if i want to load my pdf file with angular-pdfjs, i get a Cross Origin Error, because Allow-Acces-Control-Origin "*" didn't works for my pdf-url.

(https://img3.picload.org/image/roirrgcw/corsworksnot.png)

But if i using instead of ASP.net Cross Origin Support the Allow-Access-Control of IIS7 in Web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested- With, Content-Type, Accept" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

it works and the pdf will be loaded correctly.

(https://picload.org/image/roirrgci/corsworks.jpg)

But the problem is, at the moment the page is loaded via "file://" and so i get 
an error because there is no Access-Control-Allow-Origin for 'null'. That means, my pdf is loading correctly this way, but the login, pictures... won't be loaded anymore. So my question is, if someone knows how i can change the WebApiConfig-Implementation that my pdf-file get an Access-Controll-Allow as well. Or maybe can someone tell where the error could be.

For information:

Thats the way i'm loading the pdf with angular-pdfjs:

```
<!---------------------------THE PDF VIEWER DIRECTIVE------------------------->

<div pdf-viewer="options" pdf-url="pdfUrl" id="my-viewer" class="col col-lg-10"></div>

<!---------------------------THE PDF VIEWER DIRECTIVE------------------------->
```

and thats the url, i'm using:

```
function PdfviewController(ebmGuideLineService, mediaService, $scope, $window) {
    var vm = this;
    $scope.pdfUrl = 'http://localhost:3787/NCCN_Evidence_Blocks_Melanoma.pdf';
    $scope.options = { mouseZoom: false, mousePan: false };
```

Please tell me, if you need more informations and thank you for your help.